# How to reference a grails map instance in a GSP using a variable

Tags: grails, dictionary, parameters, gsp

I'm passing a map named grossScores into a GSP and need to reference individual instances of the map using another variable in the GSP.  For example,

```
grossScore.Bob = 5
```

The posting [How to reference a grails GSP model variable indirectly e.g. via .get(...)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3810844/how-to-reference-a-grails-gsp-model-variable-indirectly-e-g-via-get) is helpful but I still couldn't get there.

I've tried:

```
${grossScore."{$player}"}
${pageScope.getProperty("grossScore.${player}")}
${request.getAttribute("grossScore.${player}")}
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try:

```
${grossScores.get(player)}
```

assuming the name of the map is grossScores, as in your question.

Answer (score 0):

You misplaced the $-symbol in your first try. It is also possible to reference the value like:

```
${grossScore."${player}"}
```

Note, however, that this solution will create problems, if you use this construct within an attribute of a grails tag, e.g.:

```
<g:set var="playerScores" value="${grossScore."${player}"}" />
```

Will NOT work, and `playerScores` will NOT be set. However there is NO syntax error displayed at all, the attribute is just ignored. This can lead to a lot of confusion. If you want to use this kind of writing, then you need to use different quotes:

```
<g:set var="playerScores" value='${grossScore."${player}"}' />
```