# Grails: I want to evaluate the name of a list when dynamically building a drop down

Tags: grails, eval

I have a generic DropDown object that holds the name of a given collection. When it is loaded I would like this name "evaluated" and the proper collection loaded.

For example:

The DropDownObject:

```
class DDObject{
  String collectionName
}
```

In the controller:

```
def collection1 = ["1","2","3","4"]
...
DDObject dd = new DDObject()
dd.collectionName = "collection1"
...
[collection1:collection1,dropDown:dd]
```

(different dropdowns share different collections over the whole controller so I didn't want to add the collection specifically to the DD object)

in the gsp - something like:

```
<g:select name="foo" from="${Eval.me(dropDown.collectionName)}" />
```

(in other words - evaluate the name of the collection and get the specific collection from the map passed from the controller to the gsp)

I realize there are other ways to do this, but is this kind of "Eval" possible in this context?

thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Evaluation in Groovy can be done with `GroovyShell`, check my example [here](http://groovyconsole.appspot.com/script/1048001). But I advice against it when you will use user input on this.

A simpler way is to use the current request to get your variable. Check example in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3810844/how-to-reference-a-grails-gsp-model-variable-indirectly-e-g-via-get).

So probably this works:

```
<g:select name="foo" from="${request.getAttribute(dropDown.collectionName)}" />
```

Comment: I see - so the map passed from the controller is the equivalent of putting an attribute in the request scope. Or, more simply - the map is the request scope attributes. Exactly what I was looking for!